# Application With Foreground Service Crashes While Rotating The Device

Tags: android

I have a foreground service in my app that I need to start when the activity is not visible to the user. And stop the service when the activity is visible to the user. This is very important for my app functionality. This is working fine now.
But When I rotate the device the app crashes with following error:

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                    Process: com.hospita.traker, PID: 2244
                                    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{51b0824 u0 com.hospita.traker/.services.EventsForegroundService}
                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7725)
                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:634)
                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

In my existing setup:

I start the service in onPause (when the activity goes into the background) and stop the service in onResume (when the activity becomes visible). This makes sense conceptually.
Rotation Issue: I believe the device rotation causes Android to destroy and recreate the Activity.  This is where the problem most likely lies. The rapid stopping and restarting of the service during rotation is likely messing up the sequence of starting the service and subsequently calling startForeground(). Please see my code let me know how to fix it.

**My Activity Code :**

```
public void startService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, EventsForegroundService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", "Monitoring for alarms in the background");
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
}

public void stopService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, EventsForegroundService.class);
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    EventsActivity.activityResumed();
    stopService();
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    EventsActivity.activityPaused();
    startService();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopService();
}
```

**My Service Code :**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");


    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, EventsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("HTraker")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_cres)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    //do heavy work on a background thread
    LOG_POST(getFromSP("usrID"),getString(R.string.app_id),getString(R.string.app_name),getString(R.string.app_ver_display),className,"LOADED", "In events foreground service now");

    startTimeHandler();
    //stopSelf();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopTimeHandler();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `onDestroy()` gets called immediately after `onPause()` and `onStop()` in the orientation change situation. This causes your `Service` to be shut down **before** `onStartCommand()` is run, which is why you get this exception thrown because `startForeground()` never gets called. Why are you shutting down the `Service` in `onDestroy() ` I thought you wanted the `Service` running when your app is not running.

Comment: @DavidWasser I call `stopService();` in `onDestroy()`  because  I need to stop the service when the user logout of the app. If I take out `stopService()` from `onDestroy()` how will the logout / app closure impact the service? wouldn't it keep running? I want to run the service only if the user locks the phone or if the activity is not visible while the app is running. As soon as the user logout / app is closed the service needs to be stopped. How to handle it?

Comment: Well, if the user explicitly logs out of the app, you can shutdown the `Service` there, instead of implicitly in `onDestroy()`. You could also try to prevent `Activity` recreation by handling orientation changes in your code instead of allowing Android to kill and recreate the `Activity` if that makes more sense for your architecture.